# Finding the largest substring of 1's

Tags: python, string

I want the largest substring of 1's

```
inp = input("ENter number")
count = 1
num = []
for i in range(len(inp)):
    if (inp[i] == inp[i+1]):
       count+=1
       num.append(count)
    count = 1
print(max(num))
```

this is the input "10110111", the output must be 3

but there is error

```
 if (inp[i] == inp[i+1]):
```

IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: It should be `range(len(inp) - 1)`. Because last iteration will have index `i+1` undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it easily. Split() method will split your string input and returns a list and you can simply find the element with the maximum length

```
inp = input("Enter number")
max_Ones = len(max(inp.split('0'), key=len))
print(max_Ones)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and then convert each group to its length:

```py
import re
inp = input("Enter number: ")
result = max(len(x) for x in re.findall('1+', input))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```
inp = input("ENter number")
count = 0
result = 0
for i in range(0, len(inp)):
    if inp[i] == '0':
        count = 0
    elif inp[i] == '1':
        count += 1
        result = max(result, count)
print(result)
```